# How to scrape Price from a site that has a changing structure?

Tags: python, web-scraping, information-extraction

I want to scrape the pricing data from an eCommerce site called flipkart, I tried using Beautifulsoup with casperjs(nodejs utility) and similar libraries but none of them is good enough.

Here's the URL and the structure.
https://www.flipkart.com/redmi-note-4-gold-32-gb/p/itmer37fmekafqct?

[image]

the problem is the layout...What are some ways to get around this?

P.S : Is there anyway I could apply machine learning for getting the pricing data without knowing complex math? Like where do i even start?

Comment: `soup.find('div', { 'class' : '_1vC4OE _37U4_g' }).get_text()` maby ?  Can you post your code ?

Comment: the problem is that the class name is dynamic.It gets update each day. They even change that section's layout!

Comment: You should probably construct your XPath in a way so it does not rely on the class, but rather on the content (`node()`) of the element you want to match. Does the `data-reactid` change as well?

Comment: Yes, I've asked a lot of devs who run price comparison websites and everyone of them said that it is better to exclude flipkart from your scraping bots because it constantly breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably construct your XPath in a way so it does not rely on the class, but rather on the content (`node()`) of the element you want to match. Alternatively you could match the `data-reactid` if that doesn't change?

For matching the div by data-reactid:

```
//div[@data-reactid=220]
```

Or for matching the div based on its location:

```
//span[child::img[@src="//img1a.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/fa_8b4b59.png"]]/preceding-sibling::div
```

Assuming the img_path doesn't change you're on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use xpath due to dynamic changing you probably could try to use a regex for finding a price in the `script` tag on the page.
Something like this:

```
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.flipkart.com/redmi-note-4-gold-32-gb/p/itmer37fmekafqct"
r = requests.get(url)
pattern = re.compile('prexoAvailable\":[\w]+,\"price\":(\d+)')
result = pattern.search(r.text)
print(result.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup
page = request.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True, attrs={'class': '_31qSD5'}):
      price = a.find('div', attrs={'class': '_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
      print(price.text)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Could you maybe add some comments in your code, so it is easier for people to see, what it does?

Comment: As was already mentioned in the question comments the author cannot get the desired elements by their class names because they are being changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

E-commerce have does not allow anymore to scrape data like before, every entity of the product like product price, specification, reviews are now enclosed in a separate “Dynamic” class name.

And scraping certain data from the webpage you need to use specific class name which is dynamic. So using `request.get()` or `soup()` won't work.

Comment: Alternatively you can scrap the content and save it locally and access the price accordingly.